# Cognos 10.2.1 - I am trying to filter on a joined query and I am getting errors

Tags: cognos

I am pretty basic so I hope I can articulate this correctly.

- I have a query 1 and query 2 to join two tables into query 3. 
  Note: Q1 cardinality = 1 to n, Q2 1 to 1
- I created a data item in query 3 that compares one item from query 1 and query 2. [DATA ITEM 1] = [DATA ITEM 2]
- results are 0 or 1, so I want to filter out only the 0s as this is my desired report output
- I keep getting these errors: 
  QE-DEF-0260 Parsing errors before or near position: 
  QE-DEF-0261 Parsing text [Query 1].[DATA ITEM 1] = [Query 2].[DATA ITEM 2] ='0'

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're trying to make two comparisons in one statement, you can't do that. Try `Query 1].[DATA ITEM 1] = [Query 2].[DATA ITEM 2]  AND [Query 2].[DATA ITEM 2] ='0'`. Although really, you'd be better off filtering for the 0s in your first queries.

Comment: Andrew's correct and I'd like to add that Cognos is probably returning an integer 0 or 1, not a string.